# Efficient autocorrect on entire text files with python?

Tags: python, data-science, linguistics

I am currently preprocessing some 100000's of sentences.
To improve our ML prediction we probably should run some sort of autocorrect/spellchecking on the data. However most implementation in python i found so far are slow. Is there an efficient and easy way to auto-correct an entire text file in python?

I tried to work with this in https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect/ but it takes relatively long (I did not implement it well, but I guess someone has already done it somewhere)

Comment: Does running the autocorrect (slowly) actually improve your prediction?

Comment: It saves us some dimensions and space since words like yessss and yes are now one thing. It might be more about reducing complexity

Comment: OK. Just consider that autocorrect is not infallible. Sometimes the "nearest" word in the dictionary is not the word that the human was trying to spell. I was trying something similar recently and decided against using autocorrect after spot-checking the "corrections" it was making. Of course your corpus and dictionary are different to mine, but definitely check for correctness before worrying about speed.

Comment: @SLuck Take a look at [SymSpellCompound](https://towardsdatascience.com/symspellcompound-10ec8f467c9b)

Comment: I noticed similar issues already, but hoped there is some easier way (maybe more reliable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vishnudev mentioned, prefer using [SymSpellCompound](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpellCompound)

According to benchmarks it's faster than other spelling correction implementations by orders of magnitude.
Please refer to this [graph](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a3464aced35b6753566de84f11fc3124e6c0b78a/68747470733a2f2f63646e2d696d616765732d312e6d656469756d2e636f6d2f6d61782f3830302f312a316c5f35704f59553341686f696a4b6656442d5161672e706e67)

If you read the code behind autocorrect, it mentions that it's based on Peter Norvig's implementation available [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

Also tried benchmarking [spacy_hunspell](https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_hunspell) but couldn't manage to improve performance timings by more than +15-2O%

Other improvements tracks:

- make use of python multiprocessing module.
- if you're using pandas, please think about using Dask framework for parallel processing.

Good luck in your task !

Comment: went with symspell compound, its pretty good and also flexible solution

Comment: was hunspell 15% worse than SymSpellCompund or 15% better?